# How to encode (ffmpeg x264) with continuous seek

Tags: batch-file, ffmpeg, video-encoding, x264

I have a batch file that encodes video files from 'Source' folder to 'Target' folder.

The batch file content is:

> for %%a in ("Source*.*") do @echo DirectShowSource("%%a") >> "batchScript.avs" && @echo MSharpen(10,120) >> "batchScript.avs" && ffmpeg -i "batchScript.avs" -n -c:v libx264 -crf 24 -c:a libmp3lame -b:a 192k "Target\%%~na.mp4" && del "batchScript.avs" pause

I'm not sure why, but when I playback the encoded files in media player classic I can only jump to discrete jumps in time and not to the exact time I clicked on.

What can be done so this doesn't happen?

Thanks all!

Comment: I see this question was downvoted - I'd be happy to hear why.

Comment: This Q&A is for programming questions only and other issues are off-topic. This explains the downvote. As for your issue can you check if you have **Fast Seek** enabled? If there's such an option active it will only seek to keyframes. See more here http://superuser.com/questions/717067/mpc-hc-seekbar-not-jumping-to-correct-position-with-mouse-click

Comment: Hi. I don't think my question is off topic as the solution involves a programmable parameter in the batch file. As to your suggestion - all the files I load in media player classic seek to any keyframe perfectly and only the encoded files (per my batch file) exhibit this odd behavior. Anyway, thanks for answering. Have a nice day :)

Comment: I didn't downvote you, I'm trying to help :). It's worh checking out the **Fast Seek** anyway since the default keyframe interval value for libx264 is 250 and the other files may use smaller values. If needed you can set a specific keyframe interval using `-g [size]` or the x264 option `keyint`.

Comment: @aergistal: Thanks! I checked using MediaInfo and it seems that all my encoded files have the values keyint=250 / keyint_min=25. And unchecking the fast seek option in MPC fixes this problem. As I'm batch encoding a whole folder of videos with varying frames per second (taken with different cameras) I don't want to tamper with the fps settings in either -g or -keyint. I guess I'll leave it as is and uncheck fast seek from MPC (VLC doesn't have a problem with my files). If you type in a concise answer explaining the difference keyint values make, I'll be more than happy to select your answer!

Comment: One option is to use `ffprobe` before the encoding in order to fetch the source file parameters. It supports XML, JSON etc as output so you could parse it to get the required values. I'll draft an answer :)

Comment: video players are for `playing`. they play, and they do it smooth. frame-accurate seeking in a general-purpose video player software is possible, but is generally a bad idea  
first, you need to make sure you have shortcuts enabled for 1-frame jump in MPC;  
second, forward seeking is usually correct, whilst backwards can yield inaccurate timestamps;  
use virtualdub for frame seeking to be sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Media Player Classic has an option named **Fast Seek** in `View > Options > Tweaks` which is enabled by default. For the sake of rapidity this options makes MPC seek only to keyframes.

Keyframes (or I-frames) don't need other video frames in order to be decoded, but they are the least compressible (aka the file size/stream bitrate will be larger with a lot of keyframes).

The default keyframe interval for `libx264` is 250 (frames) and the minimum keyframe interval is 25. At 25 frames per second, for example, this means a keyframe every 250/25=10 seconds or less.

Of course this will make seeking difficult if fast seek is enabled in MPC.

To reduce the keyframe interval you can either specify a GOP size using `-g [size]` or by using the x264 option `keyint=[size]`.

Eg: for 25 fps and a GOP size 75 there is a keyframe every max. 3 seconds.